# What is the objective Scikit-learn's Random Forest classifier is optimizing at each node?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn

I would like to ask what is the specific objective function that Scikit-learn's Random Forest classifier is optimizing at each node for the "Entropy" option.

My understanding is that entropy is used as a measure here to split the training data reaching a particular node to the left and right subtree by ensuring that the split is done in such a way that the training data within each split is as "pure" as possible. However, what function is used to split the data? A linear separator? Axis-aligned linear separator? Conic-section?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Axis-aligned separator (that is a single-feature threshold).

**Edit**: I think the OP understood the answer but here is a bit more details for other readers as suggested in the comment: the current implementation of decision trees in scikit-learn (and hence ensembles of them like Random Forests) is implemented as a tree of binary decision nodes where each node compares one feature value of the sample to a threshold (learned by minimizing an impurity criterion such as GINI or entropy). The leaves of the trees output the majority class or the mean value of the target variable of the training samples that ended up in that leaf after following the path of binary decisions from the root of the tree.

There exists more complex variants of Decision Trees that build decision nodes that consider more than one feature at once (for instance Oblique Trees) but they are currently not implemented in scikit-learn.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality due to its length, but I don't think it's not an answer to the question. Would you mind simply expanding on it a little / adding a few details to make it more helpful for a future reader who's a bit lost?

Comment: +1 thanks @ogrisel. Because the options for the number of features in the RF was sqrt etc., I thought it was considering more than one feature at each node, which was typical of what was usually given in the literature... Seems like that is not the case. Thanks.

Comment: No `max_features` is only used to control the 'randomness' level of the Random Forest. At each node it would only consider a subset of `max_features` sampled uniformly from all the available features to find the best feature to split on.